# typescript - async method is returning observable, not its final data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm newbie in typescript and having some difficult to understand async concepts.

my `page.ts` file

```
myfunction(){
  this.myService.callApiMethod().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);  <<<<<<<====== I WANT HTTP DATA HERE
  });
}
```

my `service` file

```
async callApiMethod(setupData){

  return this.http.post(this.env.API_URL+'/endpoint', data).pipe(
    tap(response => {
      return response;
    })
  );

}
```

So the `console.log(data);` is showing this:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: DoOperator}
```

How can I make it grab the http response data?

Comment: This 101 stuff...please go through the docs -https://angular.io/guide/observables. Observables are asynchronous by nature and so you get the data with a subscription callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a `Promise` from your service:

```
async callApiMethod(setupData){
  return this.http.post(this.env.API_URL+'/endpoint', data).toPromise();
}
```

And then get your data like this:

```
async myfunction() {
  const data = await this.myService.callApiMethod();
}
```

I for myself switched from using Promises to Angulars Observables, because these fit much better in angular environment.

Comment: You're welcome. Would love to hear why this answer got downvoted.